# Need suggestions for fast and efficient way to parse AWS Pricing List json files

Tags: json, python-3.x, amazon-web-services

I am trying to parse pricing list json files for some aws services. After parsing I am randomly picking a key from key list to get the data. Currently my code loads the json files one at a time, which takes time. I would like to get some suggestions on how I can speed up this process.

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON is in JSONL format (i.e. one JSON object per line, with no multi-line objects), then you can load the files into [S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/gsg/GetStartedWithS3.html) and use [AWS Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/what-is.html) to run SQL queries on the data, aggregate fields, etc. You can also [connect to Athena with JDBC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html) for programmatic access.

Comment: That would work if I know what data I am looking for. Currently I am picking the data randomly. Sorry, I did not mention that in the question previously, updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up creating a database on redis server.